# View does not update with changing viewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

I have a userControl named `SensorControl` which I want to bind its dataContext to a viewModel class named `SensorModel`.
The binding is successful and the **initial values** of viewModel is visible in the userControl, but the problem is that when I **change** the viewModel's properties, the **userControl does not update**, and I have to manually update that (by assigning null to its dataContext and assigning the viewModel again).
Here is a simplified example of my code.

SensorControl.xml:

```
<UserControl ...[other attributes]... DataContext={Binding Model}>
.
.
.
<Label Content="{Binding Title}"/>
.
.
.
</UserControl>
```

SensorControl.xml.cs (code-behind):

```
public partial class SensorControl : UserControl
{
    public SensorModel model;

    public SensorModel Model
    {
        get { return model; }
        set { model = value; }
    }
    public SensorControl(SensorModel sm)
    {
        Model = sm;
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SensorModel sensorModel_1;
    public SensorControl sensorControl_1;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sensorModel_1 = new SensorModel(...[some arguments]...);
        sensorControl_1 = new SensorControl(sensorModel_1);
        mainGrid.Children.Add(sensorControl_1);
    }
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        sensorModel_1.Title = "myTitle";
        //The UserControl does not update
    }
```

0) I implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` in `SensorModel`

1) The reason I need this, is that there is only one single concept of 'Sensor' in my project (it is a real electronic sensor) and therefore I have a single model for it (that deal with the real sensor, the database, etc), but in the UI I have multiple userControls for presenting different aspects of Sensor. So I have to create one instance of model (SensorModel) for each real sensor, and multiple userControls must bind to that (each one uses different parts of model).

2) I'm not that new to WPF, but I'm kind of new to MVVM and it's possible that I misunderstand something essential, so I would appreciate if someone could clearly explain the correct approach.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `ViewModel` should not be a part of `UserControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all of you guys, I took your advices and finally I found a way.

1) I implemented an event in the `SensorModel` that fires every time any of properties changes (name `ModelChanged`)

2) Then as Merve & manOvision both suggested, I declared a dependency property in the `SensorControl` (of type `SensorModel`) and bind ui elements to that (`Binding Path=Model.Title`)

3) Then I used the `ModelChanged` event of this dependency property in the `SensorControl` and raise an event (of type INotifyPropertyChanged) so the bindings update their value

It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

In your UserControl, remove the DataContext attribute and add an x:Name attribute. Then in your Label, bind like this:

```
<UserControl x:Name="uc">
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=uc,Path=Model.Title}" />
</UserControl>
```

I believe the issue is the DataContext can't be set to Model because binding works off the parent's DataContext which will be based on mainGrid when it gets added as a child to that. Since the property "Model" doesn't exist in maiGrid's DataContext no binding will occur so your update won't reflect. Getting the DataContext of a UserControl properly can be tricky. I use the ElementName quite a bit or create DependencyProperties on the UserControl and then set them from the parent who will be using the control.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `DataContext` to your ViewModel class in your View, and if you're applying the MVVM pattern, you should use ICommand for actions. Maybe it would be better If you'd implement a MainView class that does the logic in the background instead in the MainWindow class.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainView();
  //  sensorModel_1 = new SensorModel(...[some arguments]...);
  //  sensorControl_1 = new SensorControl(sensorModel_1);
  //  mainGrid.Children.Add(sensorControl_1);
}
```

Your MainView class :

```
public class MainView {
    public SensorControl Control {get; internal set;}
    ...

}
```

And in your xaml change the binding :

```
<Label Content="{Binding Control.Model.Title}"/>
```